# Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle' kafka spring boot

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

iam using jhipster spring boot with kafa integeration

in application.yml

cloud:
stream:
default-binder: kafka
function:
definition: memberSupplier;memberApprovalSupplier;memberEventConsumer;memberApprovalEventConsumer
bindings:
memberSupplier-out-0:
destination: member
memberEventConsumer-in-0:
destination: member
memberApprovalSupplier-out-0:
destination: memberApprovd
memberApprovalEventConsumer-in-0:
destination: memberApprovd
#        input:
#          content-type: application/json
#          destination: emu
#          group: notification
#        output:
#          content-type: application/json
#          destination: emu
kafka:
binder:
brokers:
- http://localhost:9092

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNTYPED
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNTYPED
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:181)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:54)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:356)
at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:155)
at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:123)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:935)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:586)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:763)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:438)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:339)
at com.mycompany.myapp.MembershipApp.main(MembershipApp.java:69)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)

Answer (score 1):

We ran into the same issues, in our case, the problem was with incompatible (multiple) versions of dependency **io.micrometer.prometheus** with Spring boot kafka.

There were these lines in log file:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNTYPED
...
...
...
org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:88) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNTYPED
io.micrometer.prometheus.PrometheusMeterRegistry.newMeter(PrometheusMeterRegistry.java:251)
```

So please have a look deeper into your log file whether you have the same cause.